# JAXB - XML header ignored

Tags: xml, jaxb

I am using the following code to create XML using JAXB, but when the XML is created the XML header  is not included.

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("E:\\file.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(F6207.class);
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();  
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(f6207, file);
```

How can I get the below header into my XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i use for my job, it works

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourPackageBeans);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, new Boolean(true));



        marshaller.marshal(YourObject, new File("E:\\file.xml"));
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```